# Docker - Unable to mv a file inside a container

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, jena, fuseki

I am trying to give a set of bash instruction to my docker container when it launch.[image: here is my docker file with all the instruction from line 5]

but when I try to launch this docker file everything works great until the 'mv' command as you can see here : [image: docker error telling me its not a directory]

but when I try to move the file directly from the container (the exact same command as my docker file) it works :[image]

does anyone has an idea why its not working with the docker file instruction but working fine when I run the command manually ?

Comment: `mv safetybimontology_reasoner.ttl /home/configuration` is _not_ ‘the exact same command’ as `mv safetybimontology_reasoner.ttl /fuseki/configuration`.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I edited the post with the right command @Biffen

Comment: Docker setup from the project https://github.com/apache/jena/tree/main/jena-fuseki2/jena-fuseki-docker - has various mountable directories to help local configuration.

Comment: Probably your first problem is that you've written the commands into PNG-format image files; bash can't run those.  If you actually have text files, can you [edit] the question to include the text of the script and the text of the output, rather than the opaque image files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding the creation of the folder named /fuseki/configuration in the set of instruction. It works fine and I can see this log :

```
[2022-07-05 12:41:26] Config     INFO  Load configuration: file:///fuseki/configuration/safetybimontology_simple.ttl
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory `/fuseky/configuration` does not exist.
In the container you are doing it the right way so just change the command in the dockerfile:

```
mv safetybimontology_reasoner.ttl /home/configuration
```

and you should be fine

Comment: Sorry my bad, I edited the post with the right command which was mv safetybimontology_reasoner.ttl /fuseki/configuration

Comment: Nice, keep up the good work! Have a nice day!